# Checking items in a list to see if they are beside each other

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

``So I'm basically trying to see if two items in a python list are beside each other. For example, if I'm looking to see if the number 2 is beside an element in this list.

example_List = [1,2,2,3,4]

It should return True. So far I have this

```
def checkList(List1):
    for i in range(len(List1 - 1)):
        if list1[i] == 2 and list1[i+1] == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

I get the error, Error:unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The issue is with this part:

```
len(List1 - 1)
```

You should change it into

```
len(List1) - 1
```

And you should use the same case for variable List1.
Change

```
if list1[i] == 2 and list1[i+1] == 2:
```

to:

```
if List1[i] == 2 and List1[i+1] == 2:
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is also a one liner:

```
def check( l,i ): return i in l and l[-1] != i and l[l.index(i)+1] == i
```

Admittedly not the nicest one but I guess still better than the nested loops

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
len(List1 - 1)
```

for

```
len(List1) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the error you are getting is because of

```
for i in range(len(List1 - 1)):
```

this should be

```
for i in range(len(List1) - 1)):
```

here is an example of code you can use

```
def checkList(List1):
    for i in range(len(List1) - 1):
        if List1[i] == List1[i+1]:
            return True
```